# Import existing playbooks in ansible ui semaphore or awx

Tags: automation, ansible, ansible-awx

Team we are having almost 100+ playbooks already written,now we need to play the playbooks from GUI,we have to import this in GUI(semaphore or AWX).

In semaphore ui there is no option ,to import the existing playbooks

how can we import the existing playbooks in ansible GUI.we are looking only opensource GUIS

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [10. Setting up a Project](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/quickstart/create_project.html#setting-up-a-project)

> You can manage playbooks and playbook directories by either placing them manually under the Project Base Path on your Tower server, or by placing your playbooks into a source code management (SCM) system supported by Tower, including Git, Subversion, and Mercurial.

Details are available at [AWX Project](https://github.com/ansible/awx)

Comment: Thanks @valdimir ,But ansible tower is licensed version right?

Comment: You might want to start with the community upstream version and optionally switch to Tower later. That's how open-source have been working for decades. [think of “free” as in “free speech,” not as in “free beer”](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html).